# select articles + multiple comments for each article in one query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables in my postgresql database. Simplified, they look like this:

```
// table: articles
+----+-----------+---------------+
| id | title     | body          |
+----+-----------+---------------+
| 1  | hello     | world         |
| ...                            |
+----+-----------+---------------+

// table: comments
+----+-----------+---------------+
| id | articleid | comment       |
+----+-----------+---------------+
| 1  | 1         | looks cool!   |
| ...                            |
+----+-----------+---------------+
```

I want to make an overview page with all the articles + the **last 3 comments** of each article. Is this possible with one query?

My queries now look like this (nodeJS):

```
let query, values, result;

let ret = [];

// query to select all articles, ordered by ID desc
query = 'SELECT id, title FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC';
result = await postgresql.query(query, []);

// store all rows in a constant
const articles = result.rows;

// loop over each article
articles.forEach(article => {
  // fetch the last 3 comments for each article
  query = 'SELECT id, comment FROM comments WHERE articleid = $1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3';
  values = [article.id];
  result = await postgresql.query(query, values);

  // store the comments in a constant
  const comments = result.rows;

  // push the article information (ID + title) and the comments in the ret array
  ret.push({
    articleID: article.id,
    title: article.title,
    comments: comments
  });
});

// ret now contains an array of objects of articles + comments
return ret;
```

I want to know if it's possible how to combine both queries into 1, **or** (if this is not possible), the best performant way to do this.

Please note that both tables are larger than the simplified versions I described here. Currently I have + 1,700 articles and +100,000 comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, a simple:

```
select id, comment from 
(select a.id, c.comment, dense_rank() over PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY c.id DESC) as rn from articles a join comments c on a.id = c.article_id) t
where t.rn <= 3;
```

So yes, you only have to use a "DENSE_RANK()" function https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-dense_rank-function/

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Here `rank()`, `dense_rank()` and `row_number()` will do the same for output but `row_number()` will be better than others for performance

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a lateral join:

```
select a.id, a.title, c.id, c.comment
from articles a
cross join lateral (
    select c.*
    from comments c
    where c.articleid = a.id
    order by id desc
    limit 3
) c
order by a.id desc, c.id desc
```